# How can I implement Hadoop in the cloudsim?

Tags: hadoop, cloudsim

1. Hi
2. hi i want to implement hadoop in cloudsim by netbeans software.
       could you please guide me.
       meanwhile i already have source of hadoop classes.

Answer (score 0):

CloudSim is a simulator and it does not perform any actual task. Hadoop is a framework which is used to solve large problems using master slave approach. If you want to deploy Hadoop framework on cloud then try making a private cloud using openstack, then create instances in it and then try to deploy Hadoop in it. It is not possible to deploy hadoop framework in cloudsim as it's just a simulator